# Consuming REST API in ASP.NET Core web application

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, swagger

I am trying to consume a REST API in ASP.NET Core. I am able to do a simple check with "Hello" to check if the services are alive or no! but when I try to consume the Getgene, I face the problem.

I was wondering should I need to define all the variables in the class model?
And how to make view for this to pass the `{gene_query}` from the user to the API?

I would be appreciated if you can help me with the beginner prospective for APIs.

This the rest_VariantValidator : https://rest.variantvalidator.org/
I am trying to implement the VariantValidator get method with gene query input.

VariantValidatorController.cs

```
 public class VariantValidatorController : Controller
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            List<VariantValidator> validators = new List<VariantValidator>();
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://rest.variantvalidator.org/hello/"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(apiResponse);
                
                }
            }
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Getgene(string gene_query)
        {
            using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpclient.GetAsync("https://rest.variantvalidator.org/VariantValidator/variantvalidator/" + gene_query ))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(apiResponse);

                }
            }
            return View(values);
        }
    }
}
```

VariantValidator.cs

```
  public  class VariantValidator
    {
        public string seqrepo_db { get; set; }
        public string uta_schema { get; set; }
        public string variantvalidator_hgvs_version { get; set; }
        public string variantvalidator_version { get; set; }
        public string alt_genomic_loci { get; set; }
        public string gene_ids { get; set; }
        public string gene_symbol { get; set; }
        public string genome_context_intronic_sequence { get; set; }
        public string hgvs_lrg_transcript_variant { get; set; }
        public string hgvs_lrg_variant { get; set; }
        public string hgvs_predicted_protein_consequence { get; set; }
        public string slr { get; set; }
        public string tlr { get; set; }
        public string hgvs_refseqgene_variant { get; set; }
        public string hgvs_transcript_variant { get; set; }
        public string primary_assembly_loci { get; set; }
        public string reference_sequence_records { get; set; }
        public string refseqgene_context_intronic_sequence { get; set; }
        public string submitted_variant { get; set; }
        public string transcript_description { get; set; }
        public string validation_warnings { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Comment: _" but when I try to consume the Getgene, I face the problem"_ - _What_ problem?

Comment: `using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())` - [you are using HttpClient wrong](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2019/09/using-http.aspx).

Comment: Why is `Getgene` a `POST`?

Comment: @Fildor 405 Error, I am not sure if I consume it in the right way or not

Comment: [405 - Method not allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405). Do you happen to need some kind of login or API Key?

Comment: ^^  - Doesn't seem like so. Check the resulting string (from your concatenation) against the allowed values (see API Doc).

Answer (score 2):

Study api https://rest.variantvalidator.org, see on your `apiResponse` before deserialize it to dictionary.